# prevent from a user to access directly to a jsp file

Tags: jsp, servlets

let's say i have a servlet that forwards a request to a jsp file that contains a list of products.
for example, `Login.java` is a servlet that forwards a request (upon successful login) to `Products.jsp`.
now, in `Products.jsp` i have to check first that user is indeed logged in:

```
<% if (request.getSession().getAttribute("username") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("/store/login");
    return;
} %>
```

this is in order to prevent the user from seeing the products just by writing `localhost:8080/store/Products.jsp`.
I read here some posts that it is best to avoid writing java code in jsp files.
so my question is, is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - put all JSP files in `WEB-INF/` (for example - `WEB-INF/jsp`), and only forward to them from servlets. For example, if a servlet is mapped to `/foo`, then its `doGet()` method can perform the logic you've written, and do the forward to `product.jsp`.

It might become too verbose with bare servlets though, so a framework like Spring MVC can be very helpful.

Generally, authentication checks are preformed by a `Filter` though - you put a filter which checks each request and if a user is not authenticated, the filter redirects.